# MySQL - Sort and group posts/comments by different criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement which orders comments in order of time posted and also groups sub-replies to the parent comment.

```
 |- Comment 1      (Oldest)
  |- Sub Comment   (Sub Oldest)
  |- Sub Comment   
  |- Sub Comment   (Sub Newest)
 |- Comment 2      (Newest)
```

The query is below

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM feed_comments c
WHERE c.feed = 50
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY 
       IF(c.parent_id IS NULL, c.id, parent_id), 
       c.time ASC
```

I want to modify the query to still group the comments in the same way however I would like the main comments to be NEWEST to OLDEST and keeping the sub replies OLDEST TO NEWEST

```
 |- Comment 1      (Newest)
  |- Sub Comment   (Sub Oldest)
  |- Sub Comment   
  |- Sub Comment   (Sub Newest)
 |- Comment 2      (Oldest)
```

I've been playing around with many different combinations of IF and CASE statements but can't seem to find the right solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't reference a date/time column, so I have to guess on how you represent "newest".  Let me guess that this refers to larger ids.

You can also simplify the expression using `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM feed_comments c
WHERE c.feed = 50
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY coalesce(c.parent_id, c.id) desc, 
         c.time ASC
```

Comment: Hi there is a UNIX TIMESTAMP in c.time which is the post time